# Return column(s) name(s) if cell(s) is(are) not blank (separate by a coma)

Tags: excel, numbers

Given the following table:

[Example Table (column names colored for reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B18TM.png)

what formula can I use to return into the yellow cells the name(s) of the column(s) of the blue cell(s) that is(are) not blank [separate by coma(s) if there more than one]

In the sample image I had to write the result manually. Is there any formula that can do it for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there is.  Just concatenate a bunch of IF's, testing each cell for content, and returning the contents from Row 1 (with a comma) if the test is passed.  Show us what you have tried, and, if you run into trouble, describe the problem.

Comment: I tried that, the problem is that if there is only one result, it still writes a comma. It is not “clean”.

Comment: Then there is some problem with your formula. What that problem might be I cannot say without seeing your formula

Comment: `=IF(COUNTA(C2)>0,C$1,"")&IF(COUNTA(D2)>0,", "&D$1,””)`

If I mark the second cell alone, then it returns a comma before the column name.

Comment: Be sure to add a comma after each if statement. Then, use the left function to return all but the last character

Comment: It seems that I will have to use `LEN` in order to subtract from either Left or Right. If that is the case, I don’t see how to avoid repeating all over again:

`LEFT("Everything",LEN(“Everything")−2)`

Comment: Yes, you will. Or you can use VBA

Comment: I am using Numbers instead of Excel, so I cannot use VBA. Nevertheless, there should be a better way. Thanks though.

Comment: Another option would be a helper column, A second column where you store the intermediate result and then use the left and len functions in a separate column

Comment: Best option was `REPLACE(A1,1,2,"")`, where A1 represents the entire string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end there was a better option! Instead of duplicating the result both in `LEFT` and `LEN`, I was able to use `=REPLACE(A1,1,2,””)`. That way I eliminate both the comma and the space after it without duplicating the large string or using a helper table.

`=REPLACE(IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",", "&B$1)&IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",", "&C$1)&IF(ISBLANK(D2),"",", "&D$1),1,2,”")`

This formula contain only 3 cell to be analyze, but if you use it for more than that (as I will), it will work better for you don’t need to duplicate it.